# MAF and MAP location

Tags: sparkplugs, o2-sensor, maf, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor, random-misfire

I have a 2000 Pontiac sunfire se 2.2 I’m having trouble locating the MAP and MAF sensors. The mechanic I took it to said he can’t work on my car cause it didn’t stall enough while driving my car.. told me catalytic converter, plugs and wires, o2 sensors need replaced due to it misfiring

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: please don't go changing all these things as a troubleshooting procedure.  Also, O2 sensors are in the exhaust system

Answer (score 0):

Try GM forums for help because the 2.2L 4cyl engine is universal to most GM models. No maf sensor as its always mounted between the air filter assembly and throttle body, in the plastic air tubing between the two. The map sensor is mounted on the intake manifold to measure vacuum while the engine's running, as a load sensor. A simple catalytic converter test, if its internally damaged and blocking exhaust flow) is to remove the exhaust manifold mounted O2 sesnor (upstream of the catcon) and start the engine. While LOUD, if the engine suddenly has renewed power and can be driven around the block better than before removing the O2 sensor, the catcon is blocking exhaust flow; effectively a constipated engine that can't exhale exhaust gases. No improvement, it's not a catcon problem. Stalling can be a worn out fuel pump (a fuel pressure gauge is needed to measure pressure against specs), clogged fuel filter not replaced every 100k miles, spark plugs not replaced every 100k miles, one or both ignition coils, ignition control module, crank positioin sensor. An expert in EFI systems can diagnose and troubleshoot your problem without throwing parts at the problem the average mechanic would do without experience.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following diagram should look like your engine:

[image]

MAP is at location #2. The MAP will have three wires in the connector. There may be a plastic cover over this area of the engine.

As @FDryer stated, no MAF.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much..